# Recursive function not updating parameter

Tags: python, recursion

I am passing 2 lists as params in recursive function. problem is the list does not change on second call

```
recursive_children(list1, list2)

def recursive_children(image, parent_relationship):
    print('PARENT')
    print(image)
    print(parent_relationship)
    for each_object_type in parent_relationship:
        parent_id = each_object_type['child_id']
        parent_type = each_object_type['type']

        # get children object
        sql = "select * from "
        if parent_type == "RACK":
            sql += " results_api_objectsrack t1"
        if parent_type == "FLAP":
            sql += " results_api_objectsflap t1"
        if parent_type == "SLOT":
            sql += " results_api_objectsslot t1"
        if parent_type == "LABEL":
            sql += " results_api_objectslabel t1"

        sql += " join results_api_objects t2 on t1.objectid = t2.objectid where t1.objectid = %s "
        with connection.cursor() as new_children:
            new_children.execute(sql, [parent_id])
            child_objects = dictfetchall(new_children)
            image["children"].append(child_objects)
            for child in child_objects:
                print('CHILD')
                print(child)
                with connection.cursor() as newChildCursor:
                    newChildCursor.execute(
                        """
                        select t1.child_id, t2.type
                        from results_api_advancelinks t1
                        join results_api_objects t2 on t2.objectid = t1.child_id
                        where t1.parent_id = %s 
                        """,
                        [child['objectid']],
                    )
                    child_relationship = dictfetchall(newChildCursor)
                    print('child_relationship')
                    print(child_relationship)
                    if len(child_relationship) > 0:
                        print('recursive')
                        return recursive_children(child, child_relationship)
    return image
```

`list1` and `list2` are always in the recursive call. the new ones i generate are never passed through in recursive call

Comment: Are the output of `print(child_relationship)` and `print(parent_relationship)` different?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure without seeing more about the data format or print statements but you can try thinking of this line

```
return recursive_children(child, child_relationship)
```

as saying this

```
return recursive_children(image=child, parent_relationship=child_relationship)
```

since it looks like you are trying to alter the image list with this line

```
image["children"].append(child_objects)
```

Im wondering if it's your intention to pass child into the recursive call.. or if your code should look like this instead,

```
return recursive_children(image, child_relationship)
```

If you want to maintain that append that you did to the image list. You have pass it into the recursive call.